# Random exception using XBee 2.1.0

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, xbee

I have a raspberry pi running a python application that is simply sending a packet and waiting for a response. The issue is that randomly I am getting the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbee/base.py", line 95, in run
    self._callback(self.wait_read_frame())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbee/base.py", line 399, in wait_read_frame
    frame = self._wait_for_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbee/base.py", line 131, in _wait_for_frame
    byte = self.serial.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 456, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

Does anyone know why is that message? And... do you know what could I do to fix it? I tried using Try: Except but didn't work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a while I just discovered that the problem arise because my XBee was connected via USB. I changed it to serial directly and it has been running for months without any problem.